# Windows Server 2012 R2 - One Desktop, no matter the user

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-domain, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server

I'm looking to link many Windows Servers into a Windows Domain. If possible, i would like to set up users for each person with access. However when they RDP into a server, i want it to act like they logged in as "Administrator", so there is only 1 desktop per server. Not 1 desktop per-user.

So if person A is logged into server 1, and doing things. Then person B logs into server 1, it should disconnect person A, and attach person B to that same desktop.

Another way to put this is like linux SSH keys, you can just connect to the hostname and log in right away, to any server that has that key. I want to do a similar thing with Windows Server, so we have 1 user each that works on all servers. Or some kind of "key" similar to SSH keys.

Is this possible, if so, how?

Comment: Why don't you just only allow a single user?  I highly recommend NOT using any default users if you do that.

Comment: @Ramhound, I want the ability to add/remove access for people when needed. We need an account that we can always access machines with in the event of someone else changing the password. So we want seperate logins.

Comment: There are ways using a domain policy to make is so the icons displayed on the desktop cannot be changed.  You can then modify the profile in such a way where documents are [junction/hard/symbolic ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365006%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) linked to a common location.